# EV-friendly accomodation

Tags: bookings, booking.com, airbnb, electric-vehicle

A somewhat similar question to [this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/175629/15281).

Is there any specific switch or filter at Booking.com or AirB&B or any other booking service that would allow me to search for properties that allow me to charge my EV (electric vehicle) during stay (are EV-friendly) or is it always a matter of calling given property and asking them for situation?

Any EV-friendly option suits me, if booking engines can search for something like that. I don't need a public charging station next to the hotel or house. Any ability of charging is OK. It can even be an electric cable from my ground-level room to the parking.

Comment: Did I miss something? AirBnB lists “EV charger” is the amenities list in the filters. You probably want to confirm details with the host, though.

Comment: How is this question "somewhat similar" to accommodation without neighbours?

Comment: @gerrit "Somewhat similar" by asking in the same scope: non-typical filters or switches in booking engines. For me, this is somewhat similar. You are free to disagree.

Comment: @jcaron I was thinking a bit more broadly, assuming that host could offer EV-charging right out of the wall socket. But one of the comments under the answer explained that in these days (still early "EV days") one must simply contact the host to get as much details as they need. You are, of course correct, that I should look deeper before asking, sorry.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The filters already exist.

While browsing locations at booking.com, on the left of the page you have some filters.
Under the Facilities filter, you can find *Electric vehicle charging station*.

[image: Facilities filter]

On AirBNB, on the top right there's a filter button:

[image: Filter button on airBNb]

That opens the filter overview. Scrolling down until you find *EV Charger* under *Features*

[image: Features overview on AirBnb]

Comment: Do they define what they mean as this facility being available?  Does a commercially operated charging station a 2-minute walk away count, or would it have to be owned and operated by the hotel?

Comment: @gerrit One would assume those details are in each listing.

Comment: @JoeW,gerrit:  In my experience, details of these amenities are not always given in each listing;  but one can contact the host for more information about them.  ("Breakfast" can mean anything from "full restaurant-style service" to "I'll buy some basics and leave them for you to prepare yourself", for example.)  That may be what ends up being needed here.

Comment: I've stayed in a place called "Breakfast at Tiffany's" only to be told the next morning she did not have any breakfast…

Comment: I couldn't find anything about the charger location. Also not clear if a charger is free(included) in the price or they want a certain price or the charger accepts a charging pass. 
For that information I think you'll need to contact the host. 
It's still "early" days in EV charging and sleeping facilities. For now that information isn't always clear from a listing itself.

Comment: That meant, @gerrit, that you could _eat_ your breakfast at Tiffany's, not that she would _provide_ it. Heck, Tiffany probably doesn't eat breakfast - gotta maintain her figure, you know... :D

Comment: @FreeMan It's pretty hard for a store to eat.  You have seen the [movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakfast_at_Tiffany%27s_(film)) haven't you??

Comment: I have indeed, @PeterM, and I discovered that Holly Golightly looks shockingly like my mother! (Or, possibly, vice versa...)